# Understanding Classification model results

Tags: classification, ensemble-modeling, binary-classification

In a certain binary classifcation problem I am getting a AUC of 1 and Accuracy,FI,Recall,Precision of ~99.7 both in train,test and holdout sets.
But when I run the model on unlabelled data which I want to predict, I feel there is something wrong, as my model is able to predict only 100 1s and the rest 1.3 lakhs tagged 0, which seems very wrong.

What should I make out of this? Is there really a problem with my model?How can I troubleshoot this as its performing well on many sample splits of train data

Comment: What is the proportion of positive negative instances in the training data and test data?

Answer (score 0):

Their seems to be class imbalance issue one of your class is Minority while the other is majority. So you will get high accuracy even if the minority class is not having good accurate . one of the way to check this is to find out class wise accuracy .you can do this by using classification report function of sklearn. there are separate notes on class

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/113453/138894

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I don't see how the AUC can be 1 in this case.

Comment: yes all the other metrics are around 99p andAUC is 1 . prop of 1 :0 40:60

Comment: Can you share code ?